# Deriving a PDE from a function.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a long and difficult real valued  function, u, derived from a Fourier Transformation of a set of data. By having this function I can plot the data as a function. However, having also its derivatives, is there a method I can use to derive a PDE of the relationship between the function u and its derivatives?

Comment: I think that that heavily depends on the context. What does the data represent, what does the function model? Data as a function of time? Can you use physics analogies (position, velocity acceleration) ? Are rates of change relevant? Is there any fundamental law or first principle to use (again physics, or in eg finance, arbitrage)? Is the data seasonal? Just asking “I have a function, can I derive a PDE for it?” is too broad, in my opinion.

Comment: @NapD.Lover It is a function of a slightly irregular wave behaviour, actually, rogue waves in the middle of a wave train. I was thinking if there is a formula of some kind that one could use to construct the PDE problem out of the solution, rather than the inverse which is more usual.